# Excel VBA: force open XL2003 workbook from XL2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2003

We have code in an XL2010 workbook that is trying to open an XL2003 workbook through vba with `Workbook.open` and failing.

The error message is

> Office has detected a problem with this file. To help protect your computer this file cannot be opened.

Unfortunately we cannot set the folder containing the source workbooks as a trusted location.  The environment is windows XP.

Is there a way to force the opening of the workbook through VBA?  Our current idea is to recreate the code in the XL2003 workbook until we find what is causing this error - alternatively, we're thinking there might be some option in `Workbook.open` that forces a workbook to open?

Comment: For clarity, You have an XL2010 workbook with VBA code that is calling the workbook.open event handler in an XL2003-format workbook. is this correct? Or is the VBA in the XL2010 workbook opening the XL2003 workbook, which triggers the Workbook.open event?

Comment: XL2010 has the code to open the XL2003 workbook.  This is not to do with the workbook open event that triggers when the XL2003 workbook opens.

Comment: Do you face any error while opening the file manually using Excel 2010. Any popup notification or anything related.

Comment: It sounds like Excel 2010 doesn't trust the file's validity. Does the 2003 file come from an internet download or e-mail by any chance?

Comment: @Mohit It opens up manually in protected view.  I'm imagining a function that would work like workbook.open for both normal files and protected view files, however I'm not sure how it would be written.

Comment: @Vlad try changing the Trust Center setting using this link - https://answers.syr.edu/display/ischool/How+to+Turn+Off+Protected+View+in+Office+2010. This may be helpful if protected mode is what is creating the problem.